# Replace file button missing

Tags: files, media

I am missing a button to press when replacing a file.

Go to admin/content/file and edit a file.

For example: i am on file 778 at /file/778/edit

[image: URL]

[image: Replace button missing]

If you look at the Replace File field, there is no Replace/Upload button! So, yes, I can only upload an image but not replace the image.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? which module are you using?

Comment: the modules I am using are Media and WYSIWYG. i don't think there are other modules involved, my apologies if there are. I also use Manual Crop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual replacement does not happen until you save the entity. There is no fancy AJAX-based form manipulation here (unlike a core file field), so there is no specific "upload" button attached to that "replace file" field.

You just need to specify your replacement file (populate that field) and then save the full form ("Save" button at the bottom) for the replacement to happen.